# PHP preg_replace markdown issue - detecting duplicates

Tags: php, regex, duplicates, preg-replace, markdown

In a project I am building I would like to use markdown as follows

```
*text* = <em>text</em>
**text** = <strong>text</strong>
***text*** = <strong><em>text</em><strong>
```

As those are the only three markdown formats I require, I would like to remain lightweight and avoid importing the entire PHP markdown library as that would introduce features I do not require and create issues.

So I have been trying to build some simple regex replaces. Using preg_replace I run:

```
'/(\*\*\*)(.*?)\1/' to '<strong><em>\2</em></strong>'

'/(\*\*)(.*?)\1/' to '<strong>\2</strong>'                                                                      

'/(\*)(.*?)\1/' to '<em>\2</em>',
```

And this works great! em, bold, and the combo all work fine...

But if the user makes a mistake or enters to many stars, everything breaks.

i.e.

```
****hello**** = <strong><em><em>hello</em></strong></em>
*****hello***** = <strong><em><strong>hello</em></strong></strong>
******hello****** = <strong><em></em></strong>hello<strong><em></em></strong>
etc
```

When ideally it would create

```
****hello**** = *<strong><em>hello</em></strong>*
*****hello***** = **<strong><em>hello</em></strong>**
******hello****** = ***<strong><em>hello</em></strong>***
etc
```

Ignoring the un-required stars (so it would become clear to the user they made a mistake, and more importantly, the rendered HTML remains valid).

I presume there must be some way to modify my regex to do this but I cannot for the life of my work it out, even after a whole day trying!

I would also be happy with the result of

```
******hello****** = <strong><em>hello</em></strong>
```

So please, can anybody help me?

Also please consider uneven stars. In this case the below scenario would be ideal.

```
***hello* = **<em>hello</em>
```

And the time when a star should be part of the body and not detected, such as if a user inputs:

```
'terms and conditions may apply*'

or

'I give the film 5* out of 10'
```

Many many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try different capturing pattern (match anything except `*` one or more times),

```
'/(\*\*\*)([^*]+)\1/'
```

Comment: Thank you! Thats certainly improved things.

New result is now

**** = <p><em><strong><em>hello</em></strong></em>
***** = <strong><strong><em>hello</em></strong></strong>
****** = <em><strong><strong><em>hello</em></strong></strong></em>

Which is at least (while bizarre) valid HTML.

Do you perhaps know how to set so the bonus stars just render as * and do not get modified at all?

Also, I would very, very much appreciate if you could explain why your modification resulted in such a change. I understand my original code but do not quite understand how your modification is working.

Comment: Actually I cannot use this code as with your pattern you suggest now something like:

'terms and conditions may apply*' (i.e. * as part of the body) turns into an EM whereas with the pattern before, it would remain as just text if it was the only star

Comment: @user2514246 `[^* ]+` could avoid spaces between `*`

Comment: Improves things slightly, but with 4SATRSthis4SATRS I still end up with crazy lines </em><strong><em>this</em></strong><em> when i'd really like STAR<strong><em>this</em></strong>STAR

Comment: I am working on a totally new method and solution now.
If I works well I will post it for everyone.

Comment: Your answer actually ended up saving the day with this particular pronblem - it ensures everything works in order